# How to connect Moodle App running in Chrome Browser to locally hosted Moodle?

Tags: javascript, ionic-framework, moodle, ionic5, moodle-mobile

I want to debug Javascript code while writing Mobile Support for Moodle Plugins. So I want to write console.log statement and see the output in browser console while running the app in Chrome.

The app runs in Chrome but I am unable to connect to my locally hosted Moodle.

How to connect Moodle App running in Chrome Browser to locally hosted Moodle?

I have a locally installed Moodle 4.x version and edited in config.php:

```
$CFG->wwwroot   = 'http://192.168.29.85/moodle404';
```

I have cloned the latest Moodle App built it and installed in my phone using:

```
npm run prod:android
```

In my mobile app, I am able to connect through wifi to Moodle installed in my laptop using 192.168.29.85/moodle404.

But when I run the Moodle app in a browser using:

```
ionic serve
```

The mobile app is working until the login page but try to connect with http://192.168.29.85/moodle404, I am getting error:

```
Error code: serverconnectionajax
Error connecting to the server: [Response status code: 0] Unknown error
```